# ngx-datatable footer customize

Tags: ngx-datatable

How to customize ngx datatable. I am not able to find, where I have to change the code to get rid of this total number of records and to replace it with a drop down to show items per page. My pagination are missing some icons too.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the custom footer template ( refer the link below ). so it overrides the default footer.

https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/demo/basic/footer.component.ts

## Examples

If you want to just get rid of the footer, simply use:

```
<ngx-datatable-footer></ngx-datatable-footer>
```

If you want to customise it:

```
<ngx-datatable-footer>
  <ng-template
    ngx-datatable-footer-template
    let-rowCount="rowCount"
    let-pageSize="pageSize"
    let-selectedCount="selectedCount"
    let-curPage="curPage"
    let-offset="offset"
  >
    <div style="padding: 5px 10px">
      <div><strong>Summary</strong>: Gender: Female</div>
      <hr style="width:100%" />
      <div>
        Rows: {{ rowCount }} | Size: {{ pageSize }} | Current:
        {{ curPage }} | Offset: {{ offset }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

But if You want change only "total" or "no items found" then overwrite messages property:

```
//Static messages in the table you can override for localization.
{
  // Message to show when array is presented
  // but contains no values
  emptyMessage: 'No data to display',
  // Footer total message
  totalMessage: 'total'
}
```

https://swimlane.gitbooks.io/ngx-datatable/api/table/inputs.html